# Issues with setting $scope variable to updated value of service/factory variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, firebase, angularjs-service

Would very much appreciate some help with this:

I am currently using Firebase as a backend for data that is to be retrieved through my factory:

```
var schedulesFactory = function($firebase, FIREBASE_URL) {

    var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    var schedules = $firebase(ref.child('schedules')).$asArray();

    var week = [];

    var getWeek = function() {
        return schedules.$loaded(function(data) {
            var date = new Date();
            for (var i = 0, len = data[2].length; i < len; i++) {
                for (var j = 0, len2 = data[2][i].games.length; j < len2; j++) {
                    if (Date.parse(date) < Date.parse(data[2][i].games[j].scheduled)) {
                        week = data[2][i].number;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };

    return {
        week: week,
        getWeek: getWeek,
        schedules: schedules
    };
};

angular
    .module('nflApp')
    .factory('schedulesFactory', ['$firebase', 'FIREBASE_URL', schedulesFactory]);
```

Now here is my controller:

```
var SchedulesCtrl = function($scope, schedulesFactory) {

    $scope.schedules = schedulesFactory.schedules;

    schedulesFactory.getWeek().then(function() {
        $scope.week = schedulesFactory.week;
    });

};

angular
    .module('nflApp')
    .controller('SchedulesCtrl', ['$scope', 'schedulesFactory', SchedulesCtrl]);
```

Once executed, I would expect the value of $scope.week to equal the value of schedulesFactory.week once the data has been retrieved and getWeek() evaluated. However, $scope.week remains an empty array while schedulesFactory.week correctly gets set with its value from getWeek(). What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Is $loaded async? Does it return a promise?

Comment: It looks like you may be setting week just after even though the promise seems like it is resolved after week is set. Can you just return week and use it instead `then(function(week) {`

Comment: Phix - $loaded does return a promise: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebaseobject-loaded

Dylan - Sorry, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean by returning week and using it instead?

Comment: By the way, the reason why I'm building the controller in this manner is because I want to try keeping most logic and state in the factory.